# How to detect html switch state with javascript

Tags: javascript, android-studio, webview

I have a HTML switch button (on/off) and I need to detect if it is on or off with JavaScript. Please help on how to do that?

[Here is my fiddle with the switch](https://fiddle.jshell.net/yhajfcm2/)

Comment: usin document element input is checked, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp, document.getElementById("cmn-toggle-2").checked

Comment: Just tried that and it is not working. I have updated the fiddle

Comment: i've put would be done, not done, here fiddler would see how works.https://fiddle.jshell.net/yhajfcm2/4/

Comment: can you please make it show alert when it is checked? so that show it works

Comment: look to change default start value, then the input change, chahe true, to false, and look at the input as you run is was ablo or unable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
// checking wether the switch is on or off

var cb = document.getElementById("cmn-toggle-2");
cb.onchange = function() {
 if (cb.checked) alert('The Switch is ON!');
        else alert('The Switch is OFF!');
}
```

```css
  .cmn-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -9999px;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .cmn-toggle + label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    user-select: none;
  }

  input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 58px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-2" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-2"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an 'onchange' event for checkbox element. See the code below.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <div class="switch">
      <input id="cmn-toggle-2" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" onchange="javascript:myFunction()">
      <label for="cmn-toggle-2"></label>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
       alert(document.getElementById("cmn-toggle-2").checked);
    }
</script>
```